# How to make xml programming

Tags: android, xml, rss

I am making an android application to get data from an rss feed http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=be43f7366c8bae3b485cce84308d7abf&_render=rss&jumlah=50&location=indonesia 
Can anyone please suggest an idea to take data from the RSS with XML?

Comment: See this to learn XML parsing: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Comment: thanks for u'r replay. but in xtream using java. I use xml(as client) to get data from RSS server ( http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=be43f7366c8bae3b485cce84308d7abf&_render=rss&jumlah=50&location=indonesia ). can u help me?

Comment: I didnt get your question.. can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the XMLPullParser, especially for more complex XML files: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

To get the XML file in your java code use this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=be43f7366c8bae3b485cce84308d7abf&_render=rss&jumlah=50&location=indonesia");
URLConnection httpConn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = httpConn.getInputStream();
MyXMLPullParser parser = new MyXMLPullParser();
parser.parse(in);
```